# Cannot set breakpoints on Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure what happens, I can't set breakpoints on php files, but I can do so on javascript files. I've been using vs code with php for months without a problem, I haven't changed anything, but today it is not possible to set breakpoints on the side. However I can start the debug mode.

Comment: Don't downvote if you don't know. This is a totally relevant question about a recent bug in the latest VS Code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an issue with the latest VS Code & the PHP Debug extension.

As a workaround, you can set the option in VS Code "Allow Breakpoints Everywhere"

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112288#issuecomment-743456329